# EXCEL VBA- Compare columns in different worksheets, highlight non-overlapping content

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm new to VBA, so go easy.

I have two different worksheets-- Merged Nativity Codes and 2007-2011 Nativity Codes.  I want to iterate through all the values in the 2007-2011 codes (Column B) and compare that to the values in Column A of Merged Nativity Codes.  I want to highlight the content that is in the 2007-2011 codes, but not in the Merged Nativity Codes.

I tried my hand at this VBA macro:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("2002-2006 Nativity Codes")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Merged Nativity Codes")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("2007-2011 Nativity Codes")


For Each i In ws3.Range("B2:B154")
    For Each C In ws2.Range("A1:A138")
        If i.Cells.Value <> C.Cells.Value Then
            i.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next C
Next i
```

But the problem is that " If i.Cells.Value <> C.Cells.Value Then" will be triggered if only one doesn't match.  I'm looking for something like the "all()" function in Python.  Does this exist?  Easier way to do this?

Comment: Do not know about python. But if you move the color change outside the second for loop and use a flag to identify when == is found you will achieve your result.

Comment: How does the flag work?

Comment: You would just set it to a default value before the inner loop, and inside the if statement change it. Then change the if statement to look for equals instead of not-equals. But as I think about it typing this, I realize the flag would not be needed unless you were really set, or had performance hits, from setting the cell color potentially multiple times the flag is not needed.  The key is to switch to = instead of <>.  Which you figured out yourself =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered my own question by taking the easy way out.  I first highlighted the columns of interest with red highlighting.  Then I changed the Macro to color in the columns CLEAR if it finds a match (rather than coloring it red if it doesn't find one).

**Note- I'm new to this stuff, so if you guys have a more efficient way of answering this, I'd be happy to learn.  I feel like vLookUp might be useful.

```
For Each i In ws1.Range("B2:B154")
    For Each C In ws2.Range("A1:A138")
        If i.Cells.Value = C.Cells.Value Then
            i.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next C
Next i
```